# Update null in column with existing value from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

By seeing below example, how can I update `ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO` null value with an already existing value (ex with: `9007853627`), and also update `original_order_line_no` number with equivalent `ORDER_LINE_NO`?

I will pass the `ORDER_NO` and script needs to updates rest of it.

```
ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO   original_order_line_no  ORDER_NO    ORDER_LINE_NO   
---------------------------------------------------------------------
9007853627             1                    9008142190   1              
9007853627             2                    9008142190   2  
NULL                  NULL                  9008142190   4   
NULL                  NULL                  9008142190   5
```

Desired output:

```
 ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO  original_order_line_no  ORDER_NO    ORDER_LINE_NO   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    9007853627             1                9008142190   1              
    9007853627             2                9008142190   2  
    9007853627             4                9008142190   4   
    9007853627             5                9008142190   5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ISNULL` is one way, and @yourParam here is what you are passing in for ORDER_NO

```
update yourTable
set   original_order_line_no   = isnull(original_order_line_no,ORDER_LINE_NO)
     ,ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO   = (select top 1 ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO from yourTable where ORDER_NO = @yourParam)  
where ORDER_NO = @yourParam and ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO is null
```

Comment: `9007853627` != `9008142190`

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, MIN(ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO) OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER_NO) as s
  FROM tab
  WHERE order_no = ?
)
UPDATE cte
SET ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO = s
   ,original_order_line_no = ORDER_LINE_NO  
WHERE ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO IS NULL;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd1e17cf133dc1d1511d43adffde7aa1)**

Comment: Where can I check with `ORDER_NO`?

Comment: @James123 Did you even try it?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6f4ed617a6081e75ab2b37a9fa301c75.. If you see this I don't want update all orders. I want update particular order.

Comment: @James123 Just simply add where clause [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=61a09f112b10388934202665c49f8f4e)